# Der oder Die 50 Prozent Rabatt?

Tags: word-usage, noun

Wie heißt es richtig?

> - Der 50 Prozent Rabatt gilt nur im Zeitraum von...
> - Die 50 Prozent Rabatt gelten nur im Zeitraum von...

Comment: *Prozent* ist neutrum. Bei einem Prozent wäre es demnach *das eine Prozent (Rabatt)*. Bei 50 Prozent ist es Plural, also *die 50 Prozent (Rabatt)*. Ähnlich ist es beim maskulinen Wort *Euro*. Es ist *der eine Euro (Rabatt)* beziehungsweise *die 50 Euro (Rabatt)*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nach der Hinzufügung von Bindestrichen in ersterem Fall handelt es sich um zwei grammatikalisch verschiedene, aber korrekte Alternativen:

#### Der 50-Prozent-Rabatt (gilt)

Hierbei handelt es sich um ein durchkoppeltes (d.h. mit Bindestrichen aus sonst eigenständigen Wörtern gebildetes) **Determinativkompositum**. Der *Rabatt* (Grundwort) wird durch seine Höhe (*50 Prozent*, Bestimmungswörter) näher bestimmt (*determiniert*). Genus und Numerus eines Kompositums entsprechen stets denen des Grundworts – in diesem Fall *der Rabatt* (m. Singular).

Die Durchkopplung ist orthographisch aufgrund der numerischen Schreibweise von *50* notwendig. Es ginge jedoch auch: *Der Fünfzigprozentrabatt*.

#### Die 50 Prozent Rabatt (gelten)

Hier ist *Rabatt* eine *partitive Apposition* zu *50 Prozent*. Der Artikel *die* und der Numerus von *gelten* beziehen sich auf *die 50 Prozent*. (Dass Mengenbezeichnungen unter bestimmten Voraussetzungen zwar pluralisch gebraucht, aber nicht flektiert werden, ist eine grammatikalische Besonderheit.) Entsprechend hieße es im Singular: *Das eine Prozent Rabatt gilt*.

---

Stilistisch würde ich – aus dem Gefühl heraus – *der Fünfzigprozentrabatt* oder *der 50-Prozent-Rabatt* vorziehen.

Comment: "Stilistisch würde ich ..." Ich würde sagen, das hängt davon ab, ob man die 50 % oder den Rabatt stärker betonen möchte.

Comment: Ich würde noch deutlicher klarstellen, dass die erste Version nur mit Bindestrichen oder Zusammenschreibung korrekt ist, und die zweite nur mit Leerzeichen.

Comment: Für *50-Prozent-Rabatt* drängt sich die Ersetzung durch *Rabatt von 50 Prozent* auf.

Comment: Vielen Dank. Ich denke der Hinweis auf die stilistische Betonung hat mir besonders weitergeholfen. Da es sich um eine Information handelt, in der der 50-Prozent-Rabatt von einem anderen 25-Prozent-Rabatt unterschieden wird, ist diese Option definitiv meine bevorzugte Wahl. @guidot Rabatt von 50 Prozent ginge tatsächlich in diesem Kontext auch.